# use an attribute of another class in a class (corresponding to the foreign key)

Tags: php, class

I have created two tables, one corresponding to a book (id book primary key, title and availability (boolean)) and to a borrower (id borrower primary key, name, borrowed or not (boolean), and id book foreign key).

So, I create two classes.
A book class:

```
<?php
class Book {
  public $id_Book, $price, $title, $available;
  function __construct($id_Book, $price, $title, $available){
    $this->id_Book = $id_Book;
    $this->price= $price;
    $this->title= $title;
    $this->available = $available;
  }

  

  function setPrice($price) {
    $this->price = $price;
  }
  function getPrice() {
    return $this->price;
}
function setAvailable($available) {
    $this->available = $available;
  }
  function getAvailable() {
    return $this->available;
}
function getIdBook() {
    return $this->id_Book;
}
function getTitle() {
    return $this->title;
}


}
```

and a borrowing class:

```
class Borrower {
  public $id_Borrower, $name, $password, $id_BookBorrowed;
  function __construct($id_Borrower, $name, $password, $id_BookBorrowed, $hasBorrowed){
    $this->id_Borrower = $id_Borrower;
    $this->name= $name;
    $this->password= $password;
    $this->id_BookBorrowed = $id_BookBorrowed;
    $this->hasBorrowed = $hasBorrowed;
  }

  // getters and setters
  function getName() {
    return $this->name;
}
  function getIdBookBorrowed() {
    return $this->id_BookBorrowed;
}

function getHasBorrowed() {
    return $this->hasBorrowed;
}

function setHasBorrowed($borrowed) {
    $this->hasBorrowed = $borrowed;
  }

function setIdBookBorrowed($id_BookBorrowed) {
    $this->id_BookBorrowed = $id_BookBorrowed;
  }

  

//function to borrow a book 
function BorrowBook(int $idBookToBorrow)  {
    // we look if hasBorrow is true or not, if true then we can't, if false we can
    
    if(!$this->HasBorrowed){
        // we set idBookBorrowed
        
        $this->setIdBookBorrowed($idBookToBorrow);
        // we also need to put the book non available

        // we put HasBorrowed to true
        $this->setHasBorrowed(true);
        
        


        
    }
    else{
        // function to show error mess

    }
}

//function to return book 
function ReturnBook(int $idBookToBorrow)  {
    // we check if hasBorrow is true or not, if true then we can return it, if not show error
    
    if($this->HasBorrowed){
        // we set idBookBorrowed to available, and set hasBorrow to false
        $this->setHasBorrowed(false);

        
        
    }
    else{
        // show error message

    }
}


}
```

as you can see in this class, I have to create two methods: one to borrow and the other to return the book.

Nevertheless, I have to find the id of the book (so of the book class).
How can I do it ?

Moreover, what do you think of the code?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

- from `Borrower class`, you may remove `$id_BookBorrowed, $hasBorrowed`.
- into `Borrower class`, you may add an array  property `borrowed_book_ids = []` with `add_book_id`, `remove_book_id` methods.
- you probably may need `$borrowed_by` array in your `book` class to see the id set of borrowers for that book if book quantities can be greater than 1.
- You can get help to review your code in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/